# How do I fill cells in excel with incrementing formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I feel dumb for asking this but:

I have a cell filled with

```
Sheet3!A1
Sheet3!A21
Sheet3!A41
```

When I drag it down, or use the "fill" tool I cant get it to keep incrementing by 20. Is there a way to increment this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use INDEX and some math:

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*20+1)
```

Where the `*20` is the pattern and `+1` is the first row desired.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want the address in the cell or the value at the address to be in the cell.

Below are some formula options for either result, similar idea to Scott but can be modified to reflect starting row and desired output.

[image]